# How do I use an HttpOnly jwt cookie on the frontend

Tags: express, vue.js, cookies, jwt, cookie-httponly

How do I use an HttpOnly JWT cookie on the frontend since I can't read from an HttpOnly cookie?

What's the best practice for storing the JWT after grabbing it from the HttpOnly cookie? Do I even need to store it somewhere since I already have the cookie passed from the backend?

I know local storage is not secure.

I don't know if it matters, but I'm serving my Vue app on http://localhost:8080/, and I'm running my backend app on http://localhost:3000 using Node/Express.

Answer (score 4):

`httpOnly` cookies by design are not accessible by your browser.

You have to include `credentials` with your request with whatever http client you are using:

`fetch.js`

```
// with axios
axios.post(url, formData, {
    withCredentials: true
})

// or with fetch
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

And inside your express entrypoint:

`app.js`

```
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const COOKIE_SECRET = "veryLongString";

const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    ... other cors options ...
};

app.use(cookieParser(COOKIE_SECRET));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

These configurations will automatically pass your `httpOnly` cookie along with your requests, and you can access them from your server

If the cookie is `signed`:

`const { tokenName } = req.signedCookies;`

or else:

`const { tokenName } = req.cookies;`